# Twitch API -- Get Name

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

just wondering if anyone who's experienced using JQuery or twitch API could help with this. Basically I am trying to get a username, but I do not want to have to click a button or display it in an input box.

Here is the code from the API examples:

```
  $('#get-name button').click(function() {
    Twitch.api({method: 'user'}, function(error, user) {
      $('#get-name input').val(user.display_name);
    });
  })
```

So does anyone know how I would get the username without displaying it in an input box or have to click a button to display their username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to make a call to `Twitch.api` as in the code example, but you don't need to worry about doing it inside of a click event handler.

```
Twitch.api({method: 'user'}, function(error, user) {
  // this code runs after the Twitch API returns you the user data.
  // whatever you want to do with the username goes in here.
  // for example:
  console.log(user.display_name);
});
```

Let's say that somewhere in the HTML for your page, you have the following bit for displaying the username like you say:

```
<div class="greeting">
    Welcome, <span class="username"></span>
</div>
```

Then you can use

```
Twitch.api({method: 'user'}, function(error, user) {
  $('.greeting .username').text(user.display_name);
});
```

to fill the `<span>` with the user's name.

Comment: How would I display the output without using a input box?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to do. You could use something like `$('.username').text(user.display_name);` to display it in every DOM element with the class "username", for example. What do you want to do with the user's name?

Comment: All I want to do is display it as text on a page. So it could look like: "Welcome, username"